# I am getting below error while accessing SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

Please let me know feasible solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using some server side code in your master page or content page. By default, it is disabled in SharePoint. 
To enable it, you have to add entry in web.config of your web application.

```
<PageParserPaths>
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="DocumentLibraryName/Forms/allItems.aspx" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" />
</PageParserPaths>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have resolved this issue, This issue was occurred because AllItems(default) View was corruptded. I have created new view and the issue is resolved now.

Thanks,

Sachin Shinde